Bind selection in tableview in swift
So I've been doing Swift for like 1 1/2 weeks now, and coming from Objective-C, I would have thought the following would work.
Everything I'm doing is completely without xibs.
I have a class roughly like this
class MyTableViewContainer : NSObject, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
    var selectedObjectInTable : AnyObject?
    var dataTable : NSTableView()
    var dataController : NSArrayController

    func setUp() {
        // everything else
        tableView.bind(.content, to: dataController, withKeyPath: "arrangedObjects")
        // everything else
    }

    func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        selectedObjectInTable = dataController.selectedObjects.first as AnyObject
    }
}

Another class MyController has a var myTableViewContainer : MyTableViewContainer attribute, and it has a var textField : NSTextField.
The TableView is displaying the data correctly, just like I want.
Let's say the data objects in the table have an attribute var name : String.
I would like to do something like
textField.bind(.value, 
               to: self.myTableViewContainer, 
               withKeyPath: "selectedObjectInTable." + "name"
)


But nothing happens. My data definitely does not have a nil name, the compiler doesn't complain... but I don't see the value binding taking place?
What did I do wrong?

@Rob ah dang, writing code outside an IDE sucks. Fixed

Can't you bind the text field to the array controller? textField.bind(.value, to: self. myTableViewContainer.dataController, withKeyPath: "selection.name")

@CocoaNut – It is exceedingly unclear what you are trying to achieve. See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/0255230890a86931d06a5ed439171dfb. Please just explain in plain language, not code, what you are trying to do with this text field binding. But it is almost certainly unnecessary.

@Willeke That unfortunately didnt work for me

@Rob "It is exceedingly unclear" lol no. It's quite clear I thought, but I will paraphrase what I wrote in my question in English: There's a tableview whose rows correspond to the arranged objects in an array controller. I want a text field (for example, next to the tableview), and the value of the textfield should correspond to a certain String property of the object corresponding to the selected row.

@Rob But the link fixed it for me, I think. In Objective-C, you don't need to bind selectionIndexes, but apparently that's necessary in Swift.
Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

@CocoaNut you have to bind selectedIndexes of the table view to the array controller. Bind content, selectionIndexes and sortDescriptors in Swift and Objective-C if it's a view based table view. Bind the columns instead if it's a cell based table view.

You want to bind the table view’s .content, .selectionIndexes, and .sortDescriptors to the array controller’s arrangedObjects, selectionIndexes, and sortDescriptors, respectively:
// Bind the table view to the array controller
tableView.bind(.content, to: arrayController, withKeyPath: "arrangedObjects", options: nil)
tableView.bind(.selectionIndexes, to: arrayController, withKeyPath: "selectionIndexes", options: nil)
tableView.bind(.sortDescriptors, to: arrayController, withKeyPath: "sortDescriptors", options: nil)


See Populating a Table View Using Cocoa Bindings.

@Willeke – Thanks. I confess that I jumped directly from cell-based approach to diffable data sources, and I completely skipped the view-based era. Thanks for the clarification. That link was illuminating.
